# Matching Mutable Array value to index of another Array and getting other Array value at that index

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Objective: compare values stored in Mutable array(which are changing constantly) to the index of a static Array. When the values match I would like to add the object(s) of the static array to a new mutable array.

Example:

**Values of MutableArray at present state:**

> (1,2,3)

**(Index) - Values of Static Array:**

> (0) - "Zero"
>   (1) - "One"
>   (2) - "Two"
>   (3) - "Three"
>   (4) - "Four"

**Take values from initial MutableArray and compare them to the static array index's. Output the values at those index's to a new MutableArray**

> ("One","Two","Three")

The initial array is derived by passing the MutableArrayContents for a search via predicate into this:

```
NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSMutableArray* obj in _searchResults)
{
    if([_questionsArray containsObject:obj] && ![indexArray containsObject:obj])
        [indexArray addObject:@([_questionsArray indexOfObject:obj])];
}
```

IndexArray is the array of "index's".

I've tried for loops but they are not working correctly, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the values being stored in the first mutable array...NSNumber?

Comment: Hi @PhillipMills, please see edit.. I've added the code which is what is used to derive the initial array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
NSArray *staticArr = @[@"Zero",@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"];
NSArray *otherArr = @[@1,@2,@3];

NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[otherArr count]];

for(int i = 0; i < [staticArr count]; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < [otherArr count]; j++) {
        if([[otherArr objectAtIndex:j] intValue] == i) {
            [array insertObject:[staticArr objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:j];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, I've tried this however, I get a comparision between pointer and integer 'id' and 'int', warning. When I NSLog the contents of the 'array' nothing is returned..

Comment: Hello @Btxbills, that's because I had a mistake while create `otherArr`, this array couldn't be created using primitive values.

So to fix the solution change somethings 
`1)  NSArray *otherArr = @[@1, @2, @3];`
`2) if([[otherArr objectAtIndex:j] intValue] == i) {...}`
`3) [array insertObject:[staticArr objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:j];` 

It works here for me =D

Answer (score 0):

> Try this method

```
NSArray *staticArr = @[@"Zero", @"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four"];
NSArray *otherArr = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[otherArr count]];

[staticArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger staticIndex, BOOL *staticStop) {
    [otherArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *number, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (number.integerValue == staticIndex) {
            [array insertObject:string atIndex:index];
        }
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this on a tab. Please forgive any formatting issues

```
NSMutableArray *indices; //I am omitting the adding of data, it contains required indices as NSNumber objects
NSArray *staticArr = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five"];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

for(NSNumber *index in indices) {
    NSInteger idx = [index integerValue];
    If(idx < staticArr.count)
    {
        [array addObject:[staticArr objectAtIndex:idx];
    }
}
```

This will be in the order of the elements in indices array and may have repetitions in case there are repetitions in indices array.

This is the most straightforward way, there are many ways to get the subarray using Apple's API